# Does an ncurses or similar library exist which works well with fortran?

Tags: fortran, ncurses

Does ncurses library (originally developed with C in mind, if memory serves) have a port, or does an alternative exist which works well with fortran on a Windows platform?

Or, some library (since I've always used ncurses name when referring to "that sort of interfaces) which could be used to develop semi GUI on a command line prompt?

Comment: dislin is a graphing library that has a Fortran interface and is available on many platforms.  Besides graphs, it can make simple GUI windows.  Perhaps more than you have in mind...

Comment: @M.S.B. - No, I'm aiming for a semi-GUI, this type http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/27/Linux-menuconfig.png ... since i'm not actually plotting anything, but only dealing with numerical values.

Answer (score 4):

With 2003 standard C-Fortran interoperability

http://genepi.qimr.edu.au/staff/davidD/

http://genepi.qimr.edu.au/staff/davidD/Curses/pdcurses.f95

http://genepi.qimr.edu.au/staff/davidD/Curses/ncurses.f95

http://genepi.qimr.edu.au/staff/davidD/Curses/testcurs.f95

Answer (score 0):

For the alternatives, you'd need the calls in

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682087(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682087%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

If you are using IVF, the interfaces have already been done in kernel32.F90 in the IVF include directory.

On Windows platforms, to get cursor addressing to work in either kernel32 or ncurses, the Screen Buffer Size height and Window Size height in the cmd prompt properties must be set to the same value.