# Fortran: Write statement Position specifier for Terminal

Tags: fortran

This program will write 'hello' at the specified position '9' of the file 'test.txt'

```
program test
    open(31,file='test.txt',access='stream')
    write(31,pos=9)'hello'
    close(31)
end program
```

Can this position specifier be used to write on terminal?
I want to be able to do something like `write(*,pos=9)'hello'`

Answer (score 1):

The standard output is pre-opened as a sequential access formatted file, therefore you cannot use `pos`.

Why you want this? You can just use an explicit format

```
write(*,'(t9,a)') 'hello'
```

Or you can print some spaces before `hello`. You can even concatenate the spaces and the string.

Comment: when the file already contains something, then the 'pos' will write only at the position specified and will not change other contents. I wanted to do the same on the terminal. Like inserting text between something already printed. Is there a way to go 'back' on screen?

Comment: Yes, using control characters http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character or using some library such as ncurses.

Comment: But it is system dependent, beyond the Fortran standard. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792812/the-backspace-escape-character-b-in-c-unexpected-behavior

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23207032/does-an-ncurses-or-similar-library-exist-which-works-well-with-fortran